# java.lang.Object cannot be cast to java.nio.channels.SocketChannel

Tags: java, sockets, casting, socketchannel

In my app i have this code:

```
        SamplePoolableObjectFactory factory = new SamplePoolableObjectFactory();
        this.pool = new SampleObjectPool(factory);
.....

    SocketChannel channel = null;
            try {
    channel = (SocketChannel) this.pool.borrowObject();
....
}
```

i have this error:

```
Unable to borrow socket from pool java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to java.nio.channels.SocketChannel
```

what is wrong with my cast ?

```
public class SamplePoolableObjectFactory implements PoolableObjectFactory{
    private final static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(SamplePoolableObjectFactory.class);

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.apache.commons.pool.PoolableObjectFactory#activateObject(java.lang.Object)
     */
    public void activateObject(Object obj) throws Exception {
        log.debug("Activate object ..." + obj.hashCode());
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.apache.commons.pool.PoolableObjectFactory#destroyObject(java.lang.Object)
     */
    public void destroyObject(Object obj) throws Exception {
        log.debug("Destroy object ..." + obj.hashCode());
        obj = null;
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.apache.commons.pool.PoolableObjectFactory#makeObject()
     */
    public Object makeObject() throws Exception {
        Object obj = new Object();
        log.debug("Make object ..." + obj.hashCode());
        return obj;
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.apache.commons.pool.PoolableObjectFactory#passivateObject(java.lang.Object)
     */
    public void passivateObject(Object obj) throws Exception {
        log.debug("Passivate object ..." + obj.hashCode());

    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.apache.commons.pool.PoolableObjectFactory#validateObject(java.lang.Object)
     */
    public boolean validateObject(Object obj) {
        log.debug("Validate object ..." + obj.hashCode());
        return false;
    }
}
```

AND

```
public class SampleObjectPool extends GenericObjectPool {
    private final static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(SampleObjectPool.class);


    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param factory
     */
    public SampleObjectPool(PoolableObjectFactory factory) {
        super(factory);
        log.debug("New pool created with factory ...");
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param factory
     * @param config
     */
    public SampleObjectPool(PoolableObjectFactory factory, Config config) {
        super(factory, config);
        log.debug("New pool created with factory and config ...");
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.apache.commons.pool.ObjectPool#addObject()
     */
    public void addObject() throws Exception {
        log.debug("Add an object ...");
        super.addObject();
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.apache.commons.pool.ObjectPool#borrowObject()
     */
    public Object borrowObject() throws Exception {
        log.debug("Borrow an object ...");
        return super.borrowObject();
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.apache.commons.pool.ObjectPool#invalidateObject(java.lang.Object)
     */
    public void invalidateObject(Object obj) throws Exception {
        log.debug("Invalidate an object ...");
        super.invalidateObject(obj);
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.apache.commons.pool.ObjectPool#returnObject(java.lang.Object)
     */
    public void returnObject(Object obj) throws Exception {
        log.debug("Return an object ...");
        super.returnObject(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your cast. Your object factory just isn't returning `SocketChannel` objects, but normal `java.lang.Object`s.

Comment: @Kayaman my Factory is look like this `public class SamplePoolableObjectFactory implements PoolableObjectFactory`

Comment: Well why does it return `Object`s?

Comment: Well what does `SamplePoolableObjectFactory` do? Presumably it creates just `Object`, not socket channels...

Comment: @JonSkeet i edit my post

Comment: @Kayaman return object

Comment: So nowhere in any of your pool code do you refer to `SocketChannel`. How do you expect the channels to be created? I think you've misunderstood how object pools work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is an excerpt from [GenericObjectPool.borrowObject()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-pool/commons-pool/1.3/org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericObjectPool.java#GenericObjectPool.borrowObject%28%29).

```
836             // create new object when needed
837             boolean newlyCreated = false;
838             if(null == pair) {
839                 try {
840                     Object obj = _factory.makeObject();
841                     pair = new ObjectTimestampPair(obj);
842                     newlyCreated = true;
843                 } finally {
844                     if (!newlyCreated) {
845                         // object cannot be created
846                         _numActive--;
847                         notifyAll();
848                     }
849                 }
850             }
```

As you can see `makeObject()` is called on the provided instance of `PoolableObjectFactory`, so you should implement this method accordingly.

Right now you only return an instance of `Object`, which  - of course -  cannot be casted to `SocketChannel`.

```
public Object makeObject() throws Exception {
    SocketChannel  obj = ... // create channel here
    log.debug("Make object ..." + obj.hashCode());
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `public Object makeObject()` creates an `Object`. You're trying to cast that to a `SocketChannel`.

Just like cats aren't dogs, `Objects` are not `SocketChannels` no matter how much you try to cast them.

Comment: how can i do to create an `GenericObjectPool<SocketChannel>`

Comment: You can do this by implementing `makeObject()` in your factory. Take a look at my answer below.